# Color Cycle C# Bunifu

Tags: bunifu

I need help making my color cycle continue without stopping

I tried to loop the timer but that didn't work also im using bunifu

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelColor(panel1, logo);
    bunifuColorTransition1.ProgessValue = 0;
    bunifuColorTransition1.Color1 = panel1.BackColor;
    bunifuColorTransition1.Color2 = Color.FromArgb(210, 132, 120);
    timer1.Start();
}

public void panelColor(Panel h, BunifuImageButton x)
{
    panel1 = h;
    logo = x;
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (bunifuColorTransition1.ProgessValue < 100)
    {
        BunifuColorTransition bunifuColorTransition = bunifuColorTransition1;
        int progessValue = bunifuColorTransition.ProgessValue;
        bunifuColorTransition.ProgessValue = progessValue + 1;
        panel1.BackColor = bunifuColorTransition1.Value;
        logo.BackColor = bunifuColorTransition1.Value;
        return;
    }
    timer1.Stop();
}
```

Comment: someone help please

Comment: Maybe you need just an `else { }` that wraps the `timer1.Stop()` call.
Try like this:
`if (bunifuColorTransition1.ProgessValue < 100)
        {
         //stuff
        }
        else timer1.Stop();`